# Difficulty with Histogram Incorrectly Displaying Days of Tweets

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have just started using Python a few weeks ago during a university course. I am attempting to display the Average Retweets By Day of the Week for a Twitter dataset.

Unfortunately, when I go to create a histogram of my results, the graph states that all of the tweets were created on a Thursday.

I have changed the created at section to Unix time so that should not be an issue I would have thought. I have copied and pasted my code below and any help would be much appreciated!

```
data = pd.read_csv("datasets/FILENAME.csv")
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as plticker

data['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(data.created_at)

type(data['created_at'])

data['created_at'][0]

data['day_of_week'] = data.created_at.dt.day_name()

data['hour_of_day'] = data.created_at.dt.hour

data_groupedby_day = data.groupby('day_of_week')

data_groupedby_day['retweets_count'].mean().plot(kind="bar")

plt.xlabel('Day of week')
plt.ylabel('Average retweet count')
plt.title('Average retweets by day of week')
```

Comment: Testing your code with toy data gives a bar chart with values for every day of the week. Either all tweets are really from a Thursday (maybe even all from the same day?) or something is wrong with the date format in the csv.

Comment: Thank you for giving that a go Johan! The CSV was provided by the university and my colleagues have had no problem with the days of the week, so perhaps I have saved it incorrectly... At least I have some comfort that the code is correct!